# Android ImageButton doesn't respond to trackball clicks?

Tags: android

I set an ImageButton's click listener via setOnClickListener(), but it doesn't respond to trackball clicks like a regular Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. This sample code works just fine with the D-pad/trackball:

http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/Images/

Comment: I realized that the reason it wasn't responding was because it was in a GridView.  I think I should be using setOnItemClickListener rather than setOnClickListener for the individual items.  See http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg28348.html.